# Kaplan-Meier and Cox in R give different results

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

Please, can you explain, why these two formulas give different answers? Is this because Cox is a semi-parametric method and KM is non-parametric one?
I marked the differences with asterisks.

Kaplan-Meier:

```
summary(survfit(Surv(time, status)~1, data=lung),times=500)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)

 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
  500     41     138    **0.293**  0.0351        **0.232        0.371**
```

Cox:

```
> summary(survfit(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data =  lung)), times=500)
Call: survfit(formula = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung))

 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
  500     41     138    **0.295**  0.0351        **0.234        0.373**
```

When did it for the entire data set, it agrees:

```
> survfit(Surv(time, status)~1, data=lung)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)

      n  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
    228     165     310     285     363 

> survfit(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data =  lung))
Call: survfit(formula = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung))

      n  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
    228     165     310     285     363
```

Comment: These are identical for all intents and purposes.  The differences likely lay in the way these estimators are fit.  Maybe if you specified that the cox model have a lower threshold for termination then you would get what you're looking for, but I can't be certain.